# Unused parameter warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macros, clang

I am getting "unused parameter 'testString'" warning from following code. But I am using testString to log. So how come it is unused ?

```
- (void)getString:(NSString *)testString {
          ICELogInfo(@"%@", testString);
}
```

ICELogInfo is a macro for NSLog.

```
#define ICELogInfo(fmt, ...) LOG_FORMAT(fmt, @"INFO", ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_FORMAT(fmt, lvl, ...) LOG_FORMAT_NO_LOCATION(fmt, lvl, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_FORMAT_NO_LOCATION(fmt, lvl, ...) NSLog((@"%@ " fmt), lvl, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: What does it log when you run it with the warning?

Comment: It will log " INFO <--testString-->". Logging part is working fine. I don't have any problem with the output. Just that warning.

Comment: Could it be that ICELogInfo is defined as "nothing" in the non-DEBUG case?

Comment: @AmitVyawahare: It could be that the above definition is only used in the `#ifdef DEBUG` case and otherwise ICELogInfo is defined as an empty macro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't doing something wrong. This is a common problem when using macros.

As a workaround if you want to get rid of the warning, you can use this code:

```
- (void)getString:(NSSTring*) __unused testString {
          ICELogInfo(@"%@", testString);
}
```

Comment: thank you and this is a good work around but I am looking for why ?

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same "problem" before. Solved it by using the `unused` flag as e.g.

```
- (void)getString:(NSString *)testString {
    ICELogInfo(@"%@", testString);
    #pragma unused (testString)
}
```

Comment: thank you and this is a good work around as well but I am looking for why ?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Xcode are you using? This looks like a lambda capture bug in LLVM from over a year ago now:

[[LLVMbugs] [Bug 12153] New: Incorrect warning about unused parameter when using capturing variadic parameter in lambda](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmbugs/2012-March/022296.html)

as the **VA_ARGS** in those macros can be expected to work out to the same problem described in that bug report; but it should be resolved in recent Xcodes. Definitely is in Xcode 5 DP 3 that I'm running right now, your code gives me no warnings.